# Threads Output move-item verbose to file

Tags: multithreading, powershell, output

I need some help with 2 problems to my script:

I have a script that moves all pictures (if there are any) from all the subfolder locations to a new subfolder under the "PRO" folder. 
Problem 1: 
I've turned on the -verbose command on move-item in hopes of outputting it to a log.txt file, but due to the threads it gives me errors "file is allready being used by another proces".

Problem 2: 
Either i turn on the -Force command on the move-item and risk losing pictures when there are files with the same name or i find some way to rename them on the fly....

what i have sofar:

the extensions i want to move:

```
$movefiles_foto = @("*.tif", "*.tiff","*.gif","*.jpeg","*.jpg","*.jif","*.jfif", "*.jp2","*.jpx", "*.j2k", "*.j2c","*.fpx","*.pcd","*.png","*.JPEG")
```

the moving scriptblock:

```
$movefilesfoto = {
Param($extension,$loc)
$archive = "FOTO"
Get-ChildItem -Path $loc -Recurse -File -Filter $extension -Exclude $archive | ForEach-Object {
if ($_.FullName.IndexOf('\PRO\') -gt 0) {
    $Destination = Join-Path -Path $_.FullName.Substring(0,$_.FullName.IndexOf('\PRO\') + 5) -ChildPath 'FOTO';
   if (-not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $Destination -PathType Container)) {
    New-Item -Type Directory -Path $Destination | Out-Null
}        
    $_ | Move-Item -Destination $Destination -Verbose;

} else {throw ("\PRO\ path not found in '$($_.FullName)'");}}}
```

starting the jobs part:

```
write-host "move foto"
foreach ($foto_file in $movefiles_foto) 
{   
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $movefilesfoto -ArgumentList $foto_file, $location      
}
Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job | Out-File -FilePath $location\log.txt
```

My apolegies if this is too many questions at once, but wanted to avoid having to ask 3 seperate questions that might be related.

thanks in advance for any input

**UPDATE:**

verbose output to file is solved, so scratch problem 1!
The verbose info claiming it moves files from the same folder to the same folder disappeared and can't seem to be reproduced. So that leaves problem 2, the renaming

Comment: To answer question 1: if you have PSv5+, you can use stream redirection.  So you can do `Command args *>&1 | Out-File log.txt` which will redirect the streams to the output stream.

Comment: so that would give: $_ | Move-Item -Destination $Destination -Verbose *>&1 | Out-File $Destination\log.txt; 

Then i get the error that the file is allready in use by another process

Comment: Yes.  You can simplify it further to `$_ | Move-Item -Destination $Destination -Verbose 4>>$Destination\log.txt`.  Here's a [useful link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/) on the matter.

Comment: eventhough the log file gets populated with data, i still get errors in my powershell window:



 The process cannot access the file 'xxx\5\PRO\FOTO\log.txt' because it is being used by another process.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Out-File], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand
    + PSComputerName        : localhost

Comment: I'd suggest using `*>&1 | Out-File $Destination\log.txt -Force` then.  That should ignore the open handle.

Comment: nope even with the -Force part it still gives me the error message

Answer (score 0):

### Problem 1:

[An article on Stream redirection](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/) (full support introduced in PSv5)
Example:

```
Write-Verbose 'Example message!' -Verbose 4>&1 | Out-File C:\ex.txt -Force
```

---

### Problem 2:

```
Function MoveFilesFoto
{
Param([String[]]$Extensions,[String]$Location)

    $Archive = 'FOTO'

    Get-ChildItem -Path $Location -Recurse -Filter -Include $Extensions -Exclude $Archive |
      ForEach-Object {
          If ($_.FullName -cmatch '\\PRO\\')
          {
              $Destination = Join-Path 'Parent' $Archive
              If (!(Test-Path $Destination))
              {
                  New-Item -Type Directory -Path $Destination > $Null
              }
              Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $Destination -Verbose 4>&1 | Out-File $Destination\Log.txt -Append -Force
          }
          Else
          {
              Throw "Could not find \PRO\ in $($_.FullName)"
          }
       }
}
```